# Php server socket receiving continuous data from python client socket

Tags: php, python, sockets

I am trying to send data continously from the python client socket to the php server socket, I've been able to send data once and print it out. But if I put the server in a while loop to keep listening, the data it gets isn't printed out anymore. It still responds to the client if I send something back to it.

Python client code (this will be put in a function that gets called every time I send something):

```
import socket
import sys

def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 5003  # The same port as used by the server
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print >> sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % (host, port)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.sendall("Hello! Heartbeat 40!")
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print('Received', repr(data))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Php server code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

// set some variables
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 5003;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");


while(true){
    // accept incoming connections
    // spawn another socket to handle communication
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
    // read client input
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
    // clean up input string
    $input = trim($input);
    echo "Client Message : ".$input;
   // socket_close($spawn);
}
socket_close($socket);



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP output is not being send to the browser immediately. Httpd server waits for php script to finish, then send the whole output to the client.

`while(true){` in your php script runs indefinitely until dies on `socket_accept`, `socket_read`, or by timeout.

You need to define an exit point in your loop to eventually stop the script and send data to the browser.

Comment: Blew Oh, I understand now. But I am trying to send a heartbeat to the server I want to update on the screen everytime I send it. Can this be done with sockets?

Comment: Sure, but it is not trivial in PHP, since you have an intermediary webserver. I wold recommend something javascriptish like http://socket.io. The only thing is you need to understand its limitations. Another option is to use periodic pulls. In any case you need ajax js on the clientside to continuously update the page without reloading.